# Python creating objects very slowly

Tags: python, class, for-loop

I am trying to generate 1000 robot instances of `class ROBOT`

```
class robot:
    def __init__(self):
        W, H = map.size # Getting dimensions of map or image
        valid_pixels = []
        for y in xrange(H):
            for x in xrange(W):
                if ( map.getpixel((x, y)) == 255 ):
                    valid_pixels.append((x, y))

        num_valid_pixels = len(valid_pixels)

        p                  = valid_pixels[ random.randrange(0, num_valid_pixels) ]
        self.x             = p[0] + random.random();
        self.y             = p[1] + random.random();
        self.orientation   = random.uniform(0, 2 * math.pi)
        self.forward_noise = 0.0
        self.turn_noise    = 0.0
        self.sense_noise   = 0.0

for i in xrange(1000):
        r = robot()
```

It is so slow. It is taking more than 3-4 minutes. I am running `Enthought` in `Pydev`. What may be a possible problem?

But when I run the same procedure which is not under any class. It is very fast.

```
def initialize(map):
    n = 1000
    W, H = map.size # Getting dimensions of map or image
    valid_pixels = []
    for y in range(H):
        for x in range(W):
            if (map.getpixel((x, y)) == 255):
                valid_pixels.append((x, y))

    num_valid_pixels = len(valid_pixels)
    particles = []
    for i in range(n):
        p = valid_pixels[random.randrange(0, num_valid_pixels)]
        particles.append([p[0] + random.random(), p[1] + random.random(), random.uniform(0, 2 * math.pi)])
    return particles
```

Comment: Map's size is : 400, 400

Answer (score 1):

You're constructing the `valid_pixels` list 1000 times. Among other overhead, that involves 160 million `map.getpixel` calls, so it's pretty time-consuming. The second version of your code constructs the list once and reuses it for every random pixel selection, which is about 1000 times faster.